# mvc3: Multiline Text area with value defined in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, textarea, text-editor, multiline

I am want to have a text area with multiple lines and a value in MVC3. I can't seem to define a textareafor or an editorfor that has a @Value attribute which I can set. I want to have something like

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.model, 10, 15, new{@Value="try"})
```

Also, I want to be able to do this in the view because the default value will depend on an attribute of another model used within the same view.

Any thoughts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textarea` html element does not support the `value` attribute. So you can't set its value using `@Html.TextAreaFor`.

So what you have to do is this:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Model

@{
    if (1 > 2) // your logic here
    {
       Model.Description = "value1"; 
    }
    else
    {
       Model.Description = "value2"; 
    }

}

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @rows = "10", @cols = "15" })
```

Let the html helper handle the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Use Telerik control

```
 Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        .Name("Editor")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px" })
        .Encode(false)
        .Value((String)ViewBag.Contents)
        .Render();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to be recognizing "Telerik". Is there something I should do?